# How do I Write a function that takes in a string and returns the first word in that string

Tags: python, string, function, split, cpu-word

So I have several phrases X, Y, and Z
How do I create a function that selects the first word from each phrase. I have tried:

```
def first(value):
   return value[0]

def first(text)
   return text.split[1]
```

I'm totally new at this and I cant find what may work for this.

Comment: You're on the right track.  Can you add some sample data to your question?

Comment: Just to guide you, some strings could be empty, or contain a single word or be a sentence. How would you handle these cases in a single function?

Comment: thank you for you response.

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(string): #eg. "Hello World"
        string_to_list = string.split() #["Hello", "World"]
        first_word = string_to_list[0]  #"Hello"
        
        return first_word
```

Comment: Add `maxsplit=1` to avoid uneeded expansion of the list.

Comment: And just do it all in one go in the return without extra variables. Its a short enough operation that it won't confuse reviewers.

Comment: and don't use `string` as name, it's a module from standard library.

Comment: And yudheish has a good point in the commas. You may want to start with `if not string: return None` or something like that so your code doesn't raise an index error.

Answer (score 1):

```
text = "   i am mobassir"
def first(text):
  if (text is None) or (str(text).strip()==""): #if string is empty
    return None
  else:
    return text.split()[0]
get_first = first(text)
print(get_first)
```

Comment: It would be worth mentioning that this raises an IndexError if text is empty. This may be exactly the thing to do. Bad data raises exceptions. But good to note.

Comment: updated the code for handling empty strings,thanks

Answer (score -1):

This worked. But i will look at your answers to see what does work or how i can use it. Side question: Are there or can there be multiple solutions?

Appreciate your answer!

```py
def first_word(value):
  return value.split(' ')[0]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour]. This is a question and answer site, not a discussion forum. This section is only for answers. Once you have earned 50 reputation points by asking and answering you will be able to [comment on other users' questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). And if you have a new question, please post it as a separate question. You can link to this question if it provides useful context.